# How would I be able to tell if an HD Drive is failing

Tags: hard-drive

I have a 250gb drive that I'm planning on putting windows 7 on for basic use, and I'm not sure if the drive is dead as it hasn't been used in years. It is a SATA drive, I'm sure the loose object inside it when I turn it over isn't good. The drive in question is a Toshiba MK2555GSX, That or it is HDD2H24? Not too sure.

Comment: Without plugging it in and running the built-in diagnostic tests: You can’t

Comment: I have plugged it into the machine, it's not recognized by the bios. Only my 160gb internal laptop drive that I know for a fact is near dead is recognized, Yes I have tried it without the 160gb, still not recognized. I was told it worked fine, so I'm not sure.

Comment: If it was stored improperly then it’s unlik functional

Answer (score 3):

Loose objects are definitely a bad thing. If you have plugged it in to your computer (both power and data) and still don't get any feedback, that's a dead drive.

Answer (score 0):

First, if a drive is not recognized in bios, it is not a good sign.

But you can do the following:

- Download Hiren's Boot CD from the internet.

  - Burn to a CD
  - Boot from CD
  - Start Windows from CD

There you have tools to analyze the disk, if it is possible at all. 
There are many tools you can use, but in general there are a few steps to start:

The first step is to execute the SMART tests. 
Second step is the surface scan, which tells you a lot more about the drive condition.

Also if the hdd is recognized under Windows, then there is a software named Hard Disk Sentinel (Windows).
I bought it because the Pro version can reinitialize the disk, refresh the blocks, basically can lower the number of bad sectors on the hdd.

**Conclusion:**
*I would NOT put operating system on such hdd, which is in questionable condition. 
Maybe, if the tests show, that the hdd condition is good, SMART tests are not failing, and surface scan shows no bad sectors.*